# Use of Split Planes

Tags: power, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

sorry for multiposting but I have a lot of doubts on PCB Design. On my design, Texas Instruments (the chip manufacturer) tells that:

"Never route signals over splits in their perspective reference planes."

[image]

On my layout I can't put an power plane for 1.1v and 3.3v connections because I have routed the PCIE wires and the power lines comes from the south of the chip. Can I route this pins with power lines?

EDIT 1: The PCB is a Raspberry CM4 Carrier, including and USB3.0 Controller (TUSB7320) connected by PCIE Raspberry lines. The PCB Design have 4 layers, and I would like add power lines and then connect them to a polygon on power layer ( I have 3 different voltages: 5v, 3v3 and 1v1).

Comment: What's the board stackup?

Comment: PCIe design is not easy. You may get an answer to this question (if you supply enough detail), but you should learn as much as you can about high-speed design, I recommend this book: High-Speed Digital Design by Johnson & Graham

Comment: @bobflux it's a carrier for a raspberry compute module 4.

Comment: @Mattman944 Sure, this is not easy! Thank you so much for that book, I will get it.

Comment: The last few posts essentially ask how to design high frequency PCBs. This is a complex and difficult thing to do, not something you're going to be able to have explained to you in a few forum posts. I suggest trying something less ambitious first as you work up the experience and knowledge needed, or else sticking to the reference design for your chip.

Comment: How many layers PCB is this? If you can't do it with the layera you have then maybe you just need more layers?

Comment: @Justme 4 layers. The question is if I can add power planes under high speed lines.

Comment: You should add your comments to your initial question.  As in edit your question and add relevant data, so readers don't have to sift through comments.  Board stackup is how your 4 layers are assigned.  What is the purpose of having a continuous power planes?  And if you can not answer that, try something simpler as user suggests.  What alternative do you suggest to power planes under high speed lines?

Comment: I guess the whole point of getting a Pi compute module is you don't have to do highspeed design, yet you're doing it, what chip are you putting on the PCI express bus then? Is it a USB3 chip? Also, the layout for the carrier board is available on Raspberry Pi website, you can download kicad files and have a look.

Comment: I wouldn't even try routing PCIE PCB myself right now, which means you have a ways to go if you are asking these kinds of questions. My gut tells me you can't do PCIE on 4 layers. Also your quote is about REFERENCE planes, but then you start asking about power planes.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm following a Texas Instruments PCB Layout Guide and they recommend minimum 4 layers PCB, I supose that is possible to do. Yes, I was asking about routing signals over splits, because I don't know if I can create power planes under the signal traces. (I don't know the difference between a polygon connected to power net and a split plane).